# How can I create an index on lat/lon col using GIST in combination with a boolean col?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE products (
  id INT,
  latitude numeric(9,6),
  longitude numeric(9,6),
  is_location_independent boolean
);

INSERT INTO products (id, latitude, longitude, is_location_independent) VALUES (1, 56.1508469,10.2128301,false);
INSERT INTO products (id, latitude, longitude, is_location_independent) VALUES (2,56.1508469,15.2128301,true);
```

I wanna create an index that efficiently covers the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM products
  WHERE 
    (ST_DWithin( ST_GeographyFromText( 'SRID=4326;POINT(' || longitude || ' ' || latitude || ')' ), ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(13.621700 45.940900)'), 80000 ) OR is_location_independent IS TRUE)
```

I tried to create:

```
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY index_products_location
    ON products USING gist
    (st_geographyfromtext(((('SRID=4326;POINT('::text || longitude) || ' '::text) || latitude) || ')'::text), is_location_independent)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

But I get the following exception:

```
ERROR: data type boolean has no default operator class for access method "gist"
```

Now having the index without the combination with `is_location_independent` is not gonna work well. Without it, the query planner decides to do a seq scan on the table and it has millions of rows, so it's slow (8 sec).

What can I do?

PS: Postgresql 11

**Update**

Having added the following two indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX ON products USING gist (
   st_geographyfromtext(
      'SRID=4326;POINT(' || longitude || ' ' || latitude || ')'
   )
) WHERE is_location_independent;
```

and

```
CREATE INDEX ON products USING btree (
   is_location_independent
);
```

And having data like: is_location_independent: true => 1493 records and is_location_independent: false => 1 359 200

Doing the query, the query planner actually doesn't use the GEO-index, which is the one that would be really useful to the query...

```
"Finalize Aggregate  (cost=262104.14..262104.15 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=2297.030..2297.030 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  ->  Gather  (cost=262103.72..262104.13 rows=4 width=8) (actual time=2292.063..2667.239 rows=5 loops=1)"
"        Workers Planned: 4"
"        Workers Launched: 4"
"        ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=261103.72..261103.73 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=2273.565..2273.566 rows=1 loops=5)"
"              ->  Parallel Index Scan using index_products_on_is_location_independent on products  (cost=0.43..261093.34 rows=4152 width=0) (actual time=12.878..2272.703 rows=4461 loops=5)"
"                    Filter: (((st_geographyfromtext((((('SRID=4326;POINT('::text || (longitude)::text) || ' '::text) || (latitude)::text) || ')'::text)) && '0101000020E6100000AED85F764F3E2B40386744696FF84640'::geography) AND ('0101000020E6100000AED85F764F3E2B40386744696FF84640'::geography && _st_expand(st_geographyfromtext((((('SRID=4326;POINT('::text || (longitude)::text) || ' '::text) || (latitude)::text) || ')'::text)), '80000'::double precision)) AND _st_dwithin(st_geographyfromtext((((('SRID=4326;POINT('::text || (longitude)::text) || ' '::text) || (latitude)::text) || ')'::text)), '0101000020E6100000AED85F764F3E2B40386744696FF84640'::geography, '80000'::double precision, true)) OR (is_location_independent IS TRUE))"
"                    Rows Removed by Filter: 257706"
```

So as you can see, indexing is not working efficiently...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> CREATE INDEX ON products USING gist (
>    st_geographyfromtext(
>       'SRID=4326;POINT(' || longitude || ' ' || latitude || ')'
>    )
> ) WHERE is_location_independent;
> ```

Isn't the WHERE clause here backwards?  What is the point of indexing the locations for the points where locations don't matter?

If I create the index with the negated WHERE, then with a small change your query I can get it to use both indexes with a BitmapOr.

```
explain SELECT COUNT(*) FROM products WHERE 
(
    ST_DWithin( ST_GeographyFromText( 'SRID=4326;POINT(' || longitude || ' ' || latitude || ')' ), ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(13.621700 45.940900)'), 800000 )
    AND 
    not is_location_independent
) 
OR is_location_independent;
```

Gives plan

```
Aggregate  (cost=63.09..63.10 rows=1 width=8)
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on products  (cost=8.53..63.09 rows=2 width=0)
         Recheck Cond: ((st_dwithin(st_geographyfromtext((((('SRID=4326;POINT('::text || (longitude)::text) || ' '::text) || (latitude)::text) || ')'::text)), '0101000020E6100000AED85F764F3E2B40386744696FF84640'::geography, '800000'::double precision, true) AND (NOT is_location_independent)) OR is_location_independent)
         Filter: ((st_dwithin(st_geographyfromtext((((('SRID=4326;POINT('::text || (longitude)::text) || ' '::text) || (latitude)::text) || ')'::text)), '0101000020E6100000AED85F764F3E2B40386744696FF84640'::geography, '800000'::double precision, true) AND (NOT is_location_independent)) OR is_location_independent)
         ->  BitmapOr  (cost=8.53..8.53 rows=2 width=0)
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on products_st_geographyfromtext_idx1  (cost=0.00..4.38 rows=1 width=0)
                     Index Cond: (st_geographyfromtext((((('SRID=4326;POINT('::text || (longitude)::text) || ' '::text) || (latitude)::text) || ')'::text)) && _st_expand('0101000020E6100000AED85F764F3E2B40386744696FF84640'::geography, '800000'::double precision))
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on products_is_location_independent_idx  (cost=0.00..4.14 rows=2 width=0)
                     Index Cond: (is_location_independent = true)
```

Without the manual re-writing of the query to include the explicit "not is_location_independent" ANDed to the geography function, the planner can't figure out that it can use the index.

On the other hand, you could make the index with no WHERE clause, and then it would work whether you re-write the query as I suggest or not.  Since the vast majority of your records are location-dependent, there is not much efficiency to be gained by making the partial index.

I've created the 3 indexes below.  The first 2 are used on your original query, the 1st and 3rd are used on my rewrite of it.  I also made a version of the first index which was filtered for only `WHERE is_location_indepedent`, and that one would be used in preference to the original.

```
"products_is_location_independent_idx" btree (is_location_independent)
"products_st_geographyfromtext_idx" gist (st_geographyfromtext(((('SRID=4326;POINT('::text || longitude) || ' '::text) || latitude) || ')'::text))
"products_st_geographyfromtext_idx1" gist (st_geographyfromtext(((('SRID=4326;POINT('::text || longitude) || ' '::text) || latitude) || ')'::text)) WHERE NOT is_location_independent
```

Comment: That is interesting. So what exactly are the two indexes you created?

Comment: Exactly this worked. Somehow the query planner was not able to use the indexes in a combined bitmapOR unless the first one was created with `WHERE is_location_independent;` Odd

Answer (score 2):

It makes no sense to include `is_location_independent` in the index, since you have got an [`OR`](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/avoid-or-for-better-performance/) in the `WHERE` condition.

There are two possibilities:

- If many rows have `is_location_independent` set to `TRUE`, PostgreSQL will always use a sequential scan, because that is fastest.
- If only few rows have `is_location_independent` set to `TRUE`, create a second index: a regular B-tree index on `is_location_independent` alone.

  Then you can get a bitmap index scan and a *bitmap or* to speed up the query.

Comment: Du you mean that having two indexes, one: `CREATE INDEX ON products USING btree (is_location_independent)` and one `CREATE INDEX ON products USING gist (
   st_geographyfromtext(
      'SRID=4326;POINT(' || longitude || ' ' || latitude || ')'
   )
) WHERE is_location_independent;` would work? for the query? I am wondering if the latter should actually be `WHERE is_location_independent IS NOT TRUE;` instead, right?

Comment: The data is like: is_location_independent: true => 1493 records and is_location_independent: false => 1359200

Comment: Anyway, the query planner decides to do a scan on the is_location_independent index, rather than using the geo index (See updated question).

Comment: Scratch the partial index, that was a thinking error of mine. Yes, I mean two independent indexes. Given the distribution, they should both be used. Perhaps run `ANALYZE` on the table.

Comment: Well, this is why I came to the conclusion in the first place to add the `is_location_independent` to the geo-index, as I already had those two separate indexes and they are not being used. It's doing exactly what I have posted in the "update"-section of the question. An index scan on the most inefficient index... Odd.

Comment: It's an OR I have